# IDL Compilation with m2e fails, but no error

Tags: m2eclipse, idl, m2e

I've got a working Maven project setup includuing IDL compilation with the org.codehaus.mojo:idlj-maven-plugin. If I'm running mvn compile on my console, the IDL compiler works just fine. If I do this in Eclipse Indigo (3.7.2) with m2e (1.0.1), first I get the following messages (orignal paths replaced with ~~~):

```
18.05.12 13:13:55 MESZ: [INFO] Processing 1 grammar files to ~~~/target/generated-sources/idl
18.05.12 13:13:55 MESZ: [DEBUG] Processing: ~~~/src/main/idl/MyRegistry.idl
```

This is the same I get on my console along with the same configuration parameter infos.

But at the end of the m2e process I get this line:

```
18.05.12 13:13:55 MESZ: [DEBUG] Created marker 'IDL Compilation failure (org.codehaus.mojo:idlj-maven-plugin:1.1:generate:default:generate-sources)' on resource '/mypackage.myregistry/pom.xml'.
```

But there is no error or something like this showing up indicating what went wrong.

In Eclipse I already switched the Maven runtime from internal to the external one I use also on the console.

Comment: BTW: My problem is, that in Eclipse no IDL-compilation is done

Comment: After further investigation I maybe found the problem: some IDL-includes could not be resolved. The external Maven build includes the IDL files by downloading the dependecies from the local repo and extracting the IDL files. The m2e build should use the IDLs in the workspace in the other projects and probably this is not working.